# How do I select strips in the Video Sequence Editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, selection-tools

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to gather pieces of stripes to move. I don't want the all the strips to be selected but only a few. How can I select a few strips without having to select all? Others say to press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all but *I* don't want to select them all!

Comment: press **B** then drag over the strips.

Answer (score 3):

you can use some of the same selection tools that are used throughout blender.

Pressing <kbd>A</kbd> will select all.

With<kbd>B</kbd>you can do box select and draw a rectangle around the things you want to select.

You can just click-select individual strips or press <kbd>shift</kbd> and click to add to the current selection.

Clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> will inverse the selection.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> and Ctrl<kbd>Numpad -</kbd> will select more or less.

Also if you look at the menu there are a lot more options:

[image]